# setcookie php проблема

Tags: php, cookie

Делаю свой сайт и проблема следующего характера. В index.php у меня прописана строчка еще до загрузки шаблона сайта:

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/CustomFunc.php' );
```

CustomFunc грузит курсы валют с cbr.ru и загоняет их в куки. На всякий случай код:

```
<?php
function getExRates()
{
      $link = "http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp"; 
      $val = array();
      $content = file_get_contents($link); 
      $dom = new domDocument("1.0", "cp1251"); 
      $dom->loadXML($content);
      $root = $dom->documentElement;
      $childs = $root->childNodes; 
      for ($i = 0; $i < $childs->length; $i++) 
      {
        $childs_new = $childs->item($i)->childNodes; 
        for ($j = 0; $j < $childs_new->length; $j++) 
        {
          $el = $childs_new->item($j);
          $code = $el->nodeValue;
          if (($code == "USD") || ($code == "EUR")) $val[] = $childs_new; 
        }
      }
      for ($i = 0; $i < count($val); $i++)
      {
        $list = $val[$i];
        for ($j = 0; $j < $list->length; $j++) 
        {   
          $el = $list->item($j);
          if ($el->nodeValue == "USD") setcookie("USD", str_replace(",",".",$list->item($j+6)->nodeValue));
          if ($el->nodeValue == "EUR") setcookie("EUR", str_replace(",",".",$list->item($j+6)->nodeValue));
        }
      }
  }
  echo getExRates();?>
```

Затем когда у меня грузятся товары я дергаю из куков текущий курс:

```
<?php
$price = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price', true);
$currency = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'currency', true);
$margin = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'margin', true);
if($currency == "USD")
{
    $out = $price * $margin * $_COOKIE["USD"];
}
elseif($currency == "EUR")
{
    $out = $price * $margin * $_COOKIE["EUR"];
}
elseif($currency == "RUR")
{
    $out = $price * $margin;
}
if($out > 500) $output = number_format(round($out,-1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP), 0, ',', ' ');
elseif($out <= 500) $output = number_format($out, 0, ',', ' ');
echo $output." ";
?>
```

... но при первом открытии страницы если пользователь ни разу не открывал мой сайт вместо цен нули и если обновить страницу то второй раз все гуд. Курсы подтянуты и цена отображается корректно.

Что делаю не так? Почему куки срабатывают позже?

**Обновление**

@Visman  все заработало!!! Ура! Спасибо за оперативный ответ. Вот так сделал:

```
 <!-- language: lang-php -->

 if ($el->nodeValue == "USD")
 {
        $_COOKIE['USD'] = str_replace(",",".",$list->item($j+6)->nodeValue);
        setcookie("USD", $_COOKIE['USD']);
 }
 if ($el->nodeValue == "EUR")
 {
    $_COOKIE['EUR'] = str_replace(",",".",$list->item($j+6)->nodeValue);
        setcookie("EUR", $_COOKIE['EUR']);
 }
```

Comment: ну кук то вначале нет. поэтому нужна проверка - если нет кук - выполнить `getExRates();` а уже потом дергать загрузку товаров.

Comment: @Евгений, зачем вы его так странно `echo getExRates();` дергаете? Разве просто вызвать функцию нельзя?

Comment: А я же не знаю как братцы!!! Я писал на других языках поэтому так далеко зашел. PHP в первый раз вижу. Даже не знаю как функцию вызывать. Если подскажите буду благодарен.

Comment: @xaja вы наверное немножко не поняли. Когда клиент открывает index.php перед загрузкой страницы я по идее загоняю курсы в куки, и когда грузятся товары курс валюты уже должен быть в куках! Но это почему-то не так((

Comment: Как программист я очень сильно подозреваю, что где-то туплю из-за непонимания механизма работы cookie, но очень нужно решить задачу как можно быстрее так как сайт рабочий и людишки уже заходят((((( Спасайте!(

Comment: @Евгений, там где ставите `setcookie` в функции еще сразу устанавливайте аналогичные элементы массива `$_COOKIE` ;)

Comment: @Visman не совсем понял. Можно пример? плиз!

Comment: @Евгений, вместо `setcookie("USD", ... ;` ставьте `{ setcookie("USD", ... ; $_COOKIE["USD"] = ...; }`

Comment: @Visman щас попробую отпишусь. И подскажите как функцию-то дергать если не с echo

Comment: @Евгений, просто `getExRates();`

Comment: @Visman  все заработало!!! Ура! Спасибо за оперативный ответ. Вот так сделал:
<!-- language: lang-php -->

if ($el->nodeValue == "USD")
     {
    $_COOKIE['USD'] = str_replace(",",".",$list->item($j+6)->nodeValue);
    setcookie("USD", $_COOKIE['USD']);
     }
    if ($el->nodeValue == "EUR")
     {
    $_COOKIE['EUR'] = str_replace(",",".",$list->item($j+6)->nodeValue);
    setcookie("EUR", $_COOKIE['EUR']);
     }

Comment: Как в комментариях код форматировать?)))

Comment: @Евгений, комментарии не для кода. Можете оформить от себя ответ ниже. И через 2 дня, если не ошибаюсь отметить его правильным, чтобы вопрос не оставался висящим без ответа.